# Why JavaFX TableView#setItems takes ObservableList<T> and not ObservableList<? extends T>?

Tags: java, list, generics, javafx, tableview

I was wondering why `TableView<T>` method `setItems` doesn't take `ObservableList<? extends T>` as argument, but `ObservableList<T>`?

Also what would be the best way to transform `ObservableList<? extends T>` to `ObservableList<T>`. I can add all elements from 1st list to 2nd and then add listener to listen to changes, but I was wondering maybe there's better way.

Comment: your problem is not very clear. You should post code.

Comment: It would prevent you from adding items to the table via `table.getItems().add(...)` (what parameter type would you need?). So this would force the programmer to have to keep a separate reference to the list. This would be pretty inconvenient in some circumstances. What would be the benefit?

Comment: Perhaps if you want to change the table's backing list to a list of a different type, it would be better just to replace the table entirely, even if the types are related.

Comment: You can try to use inheritance **=>** `ObjA`, `ObjB extends ObjA`. Create a `TableView<ObjA>`, then create `ObservableList<ObsA> list` and add to this list `ObjA` and `ObjA`  objects. **=>** `table.getItems().add(list)`.

Comment: Also you can use the `extractor` of `ObjA` to listen changes in the list which contains `ObjA\ObjB` -> `FXCollections.observableArrayList(ObjA.extractor());`.

Comment: `public static Callback<ObjA, javafx.beans.Observable[]> extractor() {
                          return (ObjA p) -> new Observable[]{p.property};
    }` - example of ObjA `extractor`. In this case `extractor` listen only one property of Observable properties in you **ObjA** class (and **ObjB** which inherit **ObjA** `extractor`).

Comment: If you're sure to never ***write*** to the list using the list returned by `TableView.getItems()` (may lead to wrong type of object in the list as James_D wrote) the most performant way would be to simply cast your `ObservableList<? extends T>` to the raw type. But if you want to use a `ObservableList<E>` where `E extends T` with a `TableView`, why not simply use a `TableView<E>`???

Comment: The reason I want to use such list is because I have access only to a method whose return type is `ObservableList<? extends T>` and I have to display that list in a GUI. I'm never writing to a list from GUI, so I'll use casting. I'm currently using casting as all lists returned are `ObservableList<T>`, but thought if later it returns `ObservableList<E>` where `E extends T` it would throw casting exception, if not I'm ok with casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sum up the comments:

The reason why `TableView<T>` method `setItems` doesn't take `ObservableList<? extends T>` as argument, but `ObservableList<T>` is so you could add items to the list by using `TableView.getItems().add(...)`

However, if you're sure to never write to the list using the list returned by `TableView.getItems()` the most performant way would be to simply cast your `ObservableList<? extends T>` to the raw type(`ObservableList<T>`).